# Problem: Authentication. Project: C++ Onvif manager Deltaco camera

Tags: c++, xml, soap, onvif

So far I have programmed login to transfer video both over the local network and over the internet. My problem now is the authenticity of the transmission of commands to the camera. With the help of ONVIF Device Manager and Wireshark, I can see how the authenticity works. The commands are sent with HTTP POST soap+xml. I have not been able to figure out how to generate "PasswordDigest" and "Base64Binery" as below.

Part if <s:Header> from ONVIF Device Manager

```
<UsernameToken>
    <Username>
        admin
    </Username>
    <Password
        Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">
        LgjVElh3j08Lk6p3HgMmypBjEVs=   <!-- Changes after each command -->
    </Password>
    <Nonce
        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
        NZXdgMaDKUS7mIZNCDLydw0AAAAAAA==    <!-- Changes after each session -->
    </Nonce>
    <Created
        xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        2024-03-26T06:28:59.865Z
    </Created>
</UsernameToken>
```

My try with "PasswordDigest":

```
char _keys[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
void PasswordDigest() {
    // Password_Digest = Base64(SHA-1(nonce + created + password))

    /* Make the created */
    char buffer[30];
    struct timeval tv;
    time_t curtime;
    char created[256];
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    curtime = tv.tv_sec;
    strftime(buffer, 30, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.", gmtime(&curtime));
    int msec = tv.tv_usec / 1000;
    sprintf(created, "%s%03dZ", buffer, msec);
    // created = "2024-03-27T21:51:02.540Z"

    /* Make the nonce */
    uint8_t nonce[16];
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        nonce[i] = 0 + (rand() % 255); // all bytes
        //int j = 0 + (rand() % sizeof(_keys));
        //nonce[i] = _keys[j];
    }
    // nonce = "3â/ß£à@‹'o½.&"

    /* Make (nonce + created + password) */
    char input[512];
    memset(input, 0, 512);
    memcpy(input, nonce, 16);
    memcpy(input + 16, created, strlen(created));
    memcpy(input + 16 + strlen(created), psw, strlen(psw));
    // input = "3â/ß£à@‹'o½.&.2024 - 03 - 27T21:51 : 02.540Zxxxxxxxxx"

    // Test with my MD5
    uint8_t hash_1[256];
    memset(hash_1, 0, 256);
    MD5(input, hash_1);
    // hash_1 = " ¡é˜jëÆÞ¸žKg/È"

    // Test with https://github.com/vog/sha1
    SHA1 checksum;
    checksum.update(input);
    const string hash_2 = checksum.final(); 
    // hash_2 = "500773ff22f6ca354763cc5ab6b7a1a0c3d62fae"

    char* output_1 = base64Encode((char*)hash_1); 
    // output_1 = "NTAwNzczZmYyMmY2Y2EzNTQ3NjNjYzVhYjZiN2ExYTBjM2Q2MmZhZQ=="

    char* output_2 = base64Encode((char*)hash_2.c_str());
    // output_2 = "NTAwNzczZmYyMmY2Y2EzNTQ3NjNjYzVhYjZiN2ExYTBjM2Q2MmZhZQ=="

    // wireshark = "LgjVElh3j08Lk6p3HgMmypBjEVs="
}
```

The strange thing is that hash_1 and hash_2 have different values but base64Encode generates the same value.

My try with "Base64Binary":
Contrary to "PasswordDigest", I have not been able to find the prerequisites for "Base64Binary". I have tried combinations of user and password.

```
void Base64Binary() {

    /* Make (user + password) */
    char input[512];
    memset(input, 0, 512);
    memcpy(input, usr, strlen(usr));
    memcpy(input + strlen(usr), psw, strlen(psw));

    char* output = base64Encode(input);
    // output = "YWRtaW5lbWJsYTM0MTE="
    // wireshark = "NZXdgMaDKUS7mIZNCDLydwYAAAAAAA=="
}
```

Hope someone can give me a clue how to proceed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: passing a `char *` containing binary data without the accompanying length is always a red flag. Processing will stop at the first NUL byte, which can legitimately be part of your data. SHA1("Abrocoma") has bytes "60 00 ...", for example

Comment: Is `base64Encode` your implemented function? Or are you using some library?

Comment: nonce can randomly put a NULL in the byte array. If I use _keys no NULL.

Comment: No library. A few years ago I wrote base64Decode and base64Encode which I have used in other projects.

Comment: How does your function know when to stop encoding/decoding when you are not even passing the length of the input buffer? Anyways, without a good [mre], it's difficult to help you.

Comment: I use `memset(input, 0, 512);`

Comment: Let me clarify what I need help with. For authenticity to work, both `Base64Binary and PasswordDigest` must be correctly generated. I have not been able to find what parameters to use to generate the Base64Binary. PasswordDigest parameters are nonce, created and password. Should created be the date as text or timestamp. This is what I need help with. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.